# Moving buttons in Uniformgrid with animation to same X, Y coordinate using only XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have mulitple buttons in an Uniformgrid in a ItemsControl. When a user presses one of these buttons I want it to move to the upper part of the canvas e.g.(200, 0). The problem is that every button only moves a fixed amount. While i want it to move relatively to how far away it is from wanted position.
E.g a button on row 4 must move further on Y-axis then a button on 1 row.

Here is the animation:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="MoveToOutput">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2" To="-100"   Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" AutoReverse="False" />
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2" To="100"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.Y)" AutoReverse="False" />

    </Storyboard>
```

I think it has something to do with the "To=x" parameter. But cant figure out how to set it correctly
Here is the itemscontrol.

```
        <ItemsControl x:Name="SymbolControl" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" ItemsSource="{Binding Symbols}"  Margin="0,0,0,0.5" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="7" Rows="4" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <Button 
                    tec:WindowBoundInteraction.Command="{Binding KeyboardModel.UpdateSymbolsCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                    Width="200"
                    Style="{StaticResource SymbolButtonStyle}" 
                    >
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}" Height="100"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" />
                    </StackPanel>
                   <Button.RenderTransform>
                       <TranslateTransform >

                       </TranslateTransform>
                   </Button.RenderTransform>
                    <Button.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="tec:WindowBoundInteraction.Activate">
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveToOutput}"></BeginStoryboard>

                            </EventTrigger>
                    </Button.Triggers>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Try to search, but couldnt find any duplicates that uses only xaml:)

Comment: If it were me, I'd just slap a `FluidMoveBehavior` on the list to handle that automatically when you manipulate the index of the list item.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisW. Ill look into it :) ( Weird that I´ve never heard of it. Even have a WPF book, and they make no mention of if)

Comment: Give it a google, it's nifty.